# What is this 3x3x1 Rubik's cube with colored circles with colored borders?

Tags: rubiks-cube, puzzle-identification, twisty-puzzles

My son got this from a friend:

[image]
[image]

It seems to be some kind of 3x3x1 Rubik's cube. I am confused about the colours, however.

It can be solved for the coloured rings, but not for the dots - I think.

Does anyone know the name of it so I could Google for more information?

Comment: I can only find the exact same puzzle [on aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32918441342.html) without any helpful information. In general, it looks like it's a super floppy cube, i.e. a [floppy cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_Cube) with 90° instead of 180° rotations. I would assume it's also solvable for the dots, but I don't have any proof for that :)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a cheap clone of the LanLan Super Floppy Cube. It appears to have the same mechanical design with different stickers. I suspect you can solve it either with the outer rings or inner dots matching.

https://www.thecubicle.com/products/lanlan-super-floppy-1x3x3

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_Cube#Super_Floppy_Cube